# Insert Current Date/Time into XML through Ruby Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, datetime

I want to insert the current date/time into my xml feed using Rails Builder.

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FirstObject timestamp="2002-06-01T07:00:00">
....
```

I have:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.FirstObject 
....
```

What is the command to put in the current date? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml.FirstObject :timestamp => Time.now
```

Comment: Awesome, this got me 90% there. How do I format it in this format: 2002-07-08T17:34:33? Right now it outputs as timestamp="2012-05-14 04:04:10 +0000"

Comment: To answer my own question - turns out its Time.now.xmlschema